# Could not load file or assembly 'Samsung.Sap Version=1.0.0.0

Tags: c#, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I am facing a problem with developing on Tizen wearable using C#. I tried to reproduce the Samsung sample "HelloMessage". I.m using 'Samsung.Sap' protocol to communicate gears with the android app. When I tried to start the app in the watch I had this warning message: "Could not load file or assembly 'Samsung.Sap Version=1.0.0.0., Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' The system cannot find the filed specified." How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: It looks like the assembly is not imported with the application, or you are using wrong assembly.

Comment: in my project I installed Samsung.Sap from NuGet packages.
`  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Samsung.Sap" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Tizen.Wearable.CircularUI" Version="1.3.2" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution? I'm going crazy. I've even tried manually copying the samsung.sap.dll to the build folder etc.